# Double series rearrangement

Tags: sequences-and-series

if a double series converges absolutely to a sum say S, then how do i show that every rearrangement of the double series converges to the same sum S?
(i am not very good at math jaxx...sorry for the missing notations)

Comment: Do you know why it is true for an absolutely convergent single series (presumably a sum over a single index)?

Comment: Yes. I have the proof to the same for a single series...but I can't work my way up with double series